# AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 422', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: X

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

`I get AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 422', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …} whenever I run my axios post request for sending to link to user email for password change. I have made a custom hook for password change which sends a POST request to the url given. There are 3 url for different user.

1. Change customer password
2. Change admin password
3. Change brand password
   Is such an error from the front end side or the backend side please explain.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Params } from "react-router-dom";

const useForget = (userType: any) => {
  let url =
    userType === "brandpassword"
      ? "https://project2-p2.herokuapp.com/api/admins/password"
      : userType === "customerpassword"
      ? "https://project2-p2.herokuapp.com/api/customers/password"
      : "https://project2-p2.herokuapp.com/api/brands/password";
  console.log(url);

  const Forget = (email: string, setLoading: (Params: any) => any) => {
    const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (userType === "brandpassword") {
      axios
        .post(url, {
          brand: {
            email: email,
          },
        })
        .then(function (response: any) {
          console.log(response.data);
          window.localStorage.setItem(
            "token",
            JSON.stringify(response.data.brand.token)
          );
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(function (error: string) {
          console.log(error);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
    if (userType === "adminpassword") {
      axios
        .post(url, {
          admin: {
            email: email,
          },
        })
        .then(function (response: any) {
          console.log(response.data);
          window.localStorage.setItem(
            "token",
            JSON.stringify(response.data.admin.token)
          );
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(function (error: string) {
          console.log(error);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
    if (userType === "customerpassword") {
      axios
        .post(url, {
          customer: {
            email: email,
          },
        })
        .then(function (response: any) {
          console.log(response.data);
          window.localStorage.setItem(
            "token",
            JSON.stringify(response.data.customer.token)
          );
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(function (error: string) {
          console.log(error);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
  };
  return {
    Forget,
  };
};

export default useForget;
```

I'm trying to give 3 different post requests from the same code to the backened API`

Comment: First, the error isn't a `string`, it's an [AxiosError object](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors). Try logging `console.error(error.toJSON())` and look for the `response.data`. A 422 response usually includes details about what you got wrong in the request data